# Is there an efficient way to convert a set to a (list of) integers?

Tags: type-conversion, specman

I am doing some set operations with the result being a set containing (for simplification) a single integer. How can I convert the set to back to a uint? Currently I am doing something like that:

```
var my_set: set = [3];
var my_int: uint;
for i from 0 to MAX_UINT {
  if i in my_set { my_int = i; break };
};
print my_int; // should print "3"
```

I am using Specman 13.1.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, might I ask what the concrete use case is?

Comment: I would need to disclose a lot of client information to explain which I can't do. Let's just say I have a struct that holds the set of all ID values that are valid or not-valid for a bus interface.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with any built-in solutions, but you can use binary search to find the value in *O(log(n))* instead of *O(n)*:

```
    var s: set = [1884667];

    var curr_min : uint = 0;
    var curr_max : uint = MAX_UINT;
    var pivot : uint;
    var curr_set : set;

    var done : bool = FALSE;

    while (!done) {     
        pivot = (curr_max + curr_min) / 2;

        curr_set = [curr_min..pivot];
        if (s in curr_set) {
            curr_max = pivot;
        } else {
            curr_min = pivot;
        };

        if (curr_min == curr_max || 
           curr_min + 1 == curr_max) {
            done = TRUE;
        };
    };    

    print curr_max;
```

Based on this it is pretty straightforward to write a recursive function that returns all the values in a set for the cases where the set is not a singleton.

Comment: Would this also work for non-contiguous sets, Like `[3..7, 100..1000]`?

Comment: Not without modification, but it is pretty trivial to change the algorithm to support it - instead of the `in` operator you will need to use the `intersect` pseudo-method to match both halves of the set, and in case they mach recursively call the method, with the stopping condition being that the matching set is a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

I have a regular expression based solution for this. It might be slower due to string matching, but for small intervals it might actually be faster:

```
extend sys {
  run() is also {
    var my_1set : set = [1..5];
    var my_2set : set = [3..7, 10..13];
    var my_3set : set = [1..5,7..10,20..25];

    print convert_set(my_1set);
    print convert_set(my_2set);
    print convert_set(my_3set);
  };

  convert_set(my_set : set) : list of int is {
    var my_set_as_string :=  my_set.to_string();

    while TRUE {
      // split it using regexps - should always match
      assert str_match(my_set_as_string, "/(\d+\.\.\d+)(.*)/");

      result = { result;  generate_ints($1) };
      if $2 == "]" {
        break;
      };
      my_set_as_string = $2;
    };
  };

  generate_ints(interval : string) : list of int is {
    assert str_match(interval, "/(\d+)\.\.(\d+)/");
    for i from $1.as_a(int) to $2.as_a(int) {
      result = { result; i };
    };
  };
};
```

This also doesn't work for all integers (only for unsigned integers) in its current form, but that's just a matter of tweaking the regular expressions. You can check it out and see if its fast enough. If so, we/you can tweak the regular expressions to work for negative integers as well.

Comment: Very nice. For the case where the set contains only one number [x] it's even simpler.

Comment: Ah yeah, the regexp doesn't support that... Come to think of it, neither does it support [1, 2, 7..6]. This seems like a really nice exercise, I'll probably make a blog post out of this with the complete solution.